# What is the best/most efficient way to output value every x seconds during a loop

Tags: python

I have always been curious about this as the simple way is definitely not efficient. How would you efficiently go about outputting a value every x seconds?

Here is an example of what I mean:

```
import time
num = 50000000

startTime = time.time()
j=0
for i in range(num):
    j = (((j+10)**0.5)**2)**0.5
print time.time() - startTime

#output time: 24 seconds


startTime = time.time()
newTime = time.time()
j=0
for i in range(num):
    j = (((j+10)**0.5)**2)**0.5
    if time.time() - newTime > 0.5:
        newTime = time.time()
        print i
print time.time() - startTime

#output time: 32 seconds
```

A whole 1/3rd faster when not outputting the progress every half a second.

I know this is because it requires an extra calculation every loop, but the same applies with other similar checks you may want to do - how would you go about implementing something like this without seriously affecting the execution time?

Comment: Note that this program is spending almost as much time looping as doing actual work, which is a big part of the reason the time checks are adding a significant cost. Is your real program really doing so little in the inner loop? If not, the optimization you're looking for is probably irrelevant. If so, the optimization you're looking for is probably insufficient, and you should be looking into using something like numpy (which may reduce the whole operation down to under 0.5s so you don't even need to report progress…).

Comment: Also, `time.time` is not a very good way to measure performance, especially on Unix. The [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) library automatically picks the best timer for your platform, and also deals with other stuff you haven't even considered (disabling the GC cycle detector, running multiple loops, etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you know that you're doing many iterations per second, so you really don't need to make the `time.time()` call on every iteration. You can use a modulo operator to only actually check if you need to output something every N iterations of the loop.

```
startTime = time.time()
newTime = time.time()
j=0
for i in range(num):
    j = (((j+10)**0.5)**2)**0.5
    if i % 50 == 0:  # Only check every 50th iteration
        if time.time() - newTime > 0.5:
            newTime = time.time()
            print i, newTime
print time.time() - startTime
# 45 seconds (the original version took 42 on my system)
```

Checking only every 50 iterations reduces my run time from 56 seconds to 43 (the original took with no printing 42, and Tom Page's solution took 50 seconds), and the iterations complete quickly enough that its still outputting exactly every 0.5 seconds according to `time.time()`:

```
0 1409083225.39
605000 1409083225.89
1201450 1409083226.39
1821150 1409083226.89
2439250 1409083227.39
3054400 1409083227.89
3644100 1409083228.39
4254350 1409083228.89
4831600 1409083229.39
5433450 1409083229.89
6034850 1409083230.39
6644400 1409083230.89
7252650 1409083231.39
7840100 1409083231.89
8438300 1409083232.39
9061200 1409083232.89
9667350 1409083233.39
...
```

Comment: This obviously requires having a rough idea of how many iterations you can do in a sizeable fraction of 0.5 seconds… but often you have such an idea, in which case this is by far the simplest solution.

Comment: Thanks, though I just tested both yours and Tom Page's, his comes out at 26.4 seconds while yours is 30.6. Wouldn't the i % 50 still count as an extra calculation, just a bit more simple than the minus?

Comment: @Peter: It's not any more simple than the minus, but it does avoid calling `time.time()`, which (depending on your platform, etc.) may be orders of magnitude slower than doing arithmetic.

Comment: @Peter Better yet, combine our solutions. You could also probably get away with a number larger than 50 and still get accurate timings, which will further improve the speed.

Comment: @Peter: In fact, what you really want to do is tune the modulus as high as possible for your desired degree of timing accuracy. If you're writing something for general distribution obviously there's only so far you can go with that, but if you're writing a script to be run on your laptop or your server farm, you can measure things pretty exactly.

Comment: As my script is within Maya, I unfortunately can't fine tune it as it should work with anyone's computer, I just want a way to output the progress efficiently though so it doesn't need to be accurately timed. I just tried this way mixed with Toms (apologies I didn't combine them before, I thought it was the i%50 was slowing it down), and I get a marginally faster time. If it's true about time.time() being slower on some platforms, this should prove very useful, thanks :)

Comment: @Peter: Besides being slow on some platforms, `time` isn't required to have any better than 1s precision (and on some older *nixes it won't), making it a bad choice for timing every 0.5s. The right answer is to use the appropriate `clock_gettime` instead. Unfortunately, that requires Python 3.3+, but I'm pretty sure there's a backport on PyPI. (A couple years ago, there was a POSIX-specific library and a almost-but-not-quite-compatible Windows library that you need to wrap up to match each other to provide the backport yourself, but I think that's improved…)

Answer (score 2):

You might save a few clock cycles by keeping track of the next time that a print is due

```
nexttime = time.time() + 0.5
```

And then your condition will be a simple comparison

```
If time.time()  >= nexttime
```

As opposed to a subtraction followed by a comparison

```
If time.time() - newTime > 0.5
```

You'll only have to do an addition after each message as opposed to doing a subtraction after each itteration

Comment: Ah yes thanks, it totally didn't cross my mind at the time but that was what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

I tried it with a sideband thread doing the printing. It added 5 seconds to exec time on python 2.x but virtually not extra time on python 3.x. Python 2.x threads have a lot of overhead. Here's my example with timing included as comments:

```
import time
import threading


def showit(event):
    global i # could pass in a mutable object instead
    while not event.is_set():
        event.wait(.5)
        print 'value is', i

num = 50000000

startTime = time.time()
j=0
for i in range(num):
    j = (((j+10)**0.5)**2)**0.5
print time.time() - startTime

#output time: 23 seconds

event = threading.Event()
showit_thread = threading.Thread(target=showit, args=(event,))
showit_thread.start()

startTime = time.time()
j=0
for i in range(num):
    j = (((j+10)**0.5)**2)**0.5
event.set()
time.sleep(.1)
print time.time() - startTime

#output time: 28 seconds
```

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that you're not protecting `i` at all, and you're relying on it being atomic. As long as you're using CPython, and not operating on `i` outside the GIL, this is safe, but if you want to be able to run in other implementations, or if `i` is something like a `numpy.ndarray`, you will need to add a lock (or maybe come up with some lock-free implementation where you do something atomic to "commit" the value to visibility every time it's consistent, but that's more complicated to do in Python, and usually not worth it).

Comment: Ahh, while it may work well on most things, unfortunately Maya doesn't properly support threading (and i wasted a lot of time a while back trying to get it working haha), so I've gotta keep it all within one thread :)

Comment: @abarnet - this was mostly a timing check so I didn't worry about atomic access, etc... (just tagged it with a note). On python 2.x, the results weren't very good and I'm not sure i'd recommend doing it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to wait a specified period of time before doing something, just use the [`time.sleep()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.sleep) method.

```
for i in range(100):
    print(i)
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

This will wait half a second before printing the next value of `i`.

Comment: That wood be good aside from I want it to print the current progress every x seconds, as opposed to just print the next iteration every x seconds :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about Windows, [`signal.setitimer`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html#signal.setitimer) will be simpler than using a background thread, and on many *nix platforms a whole lot more efficient.

Here's an example:

```
import signal
import time

num = 50000000

startTime = time.time()

def ontimer(sig, frame):
    global i
    print(i)
signal.signal(signal.SIGVTALRM, ontimer)

signal.setitimer(signal.ITIMER_VIRTUAL, 0.5, 0.5)
j=0
for i in range(num):
    j = (((j+10)**0.5)**2)**0.5
signal.setitimer(signal.ITIMER_VIRTUAL, 0)
print(time.time() - startTime)
```

This is about as close to free as you're going to get performance-wise.

In some use cases, a virtual timer isn't sufficiently accurate, so you need to change that to `ITIMER_REAL` and change the signal to `SIGALRM`. That's a little more expensive, but still pretty cheap, and still dead simple.

On some (older) *nix platforms, `alarm` may be more efficient than `setitmer`, but unfortunately `alarm` only takes integral seconds, so you can't use it to fire twice/second.

Timings from my MacBook Pro:

- no output: 15.02s
- `SIGVTALRM`: 15.03s
- `SIGALRM`: 15.44s
- thread: 19.9s
- checking `time.time()`: 22.3s

(I didn't test with either dano's optimization or Tom Page's; obviously those will reduce the 22.3, but they're not going to get it down to 15.44…)

Comment: Ah thanks :)  Unfortunately though it looks like Maya doesn't contain the complete signal module, which is a shame considering your speedup haha (I'm stuck to the default modules so other people will be able to run the same code), hopefully it'll come in useful for others though :)

Comment: @Peter: Are you sure Maya doesn't contain the complete `signal` module? As I mentioned, if you're on Windows, you get a very stripped-down `signal` that doesn't include, among other things, `setitimer` and `SIGALRM`. Which means this solution only works if you don't care about Windows.

Comment: I wasn't quite sure if you meant it wasn't on windows or just it was also supported on other platforms aha, but yeah, it throws an error at various values including those two, saying the module object has no attribute. I thought Maya was on multiple platforms, but is obviously limited to the windows style python :)

Comment: @Peter: Maya is on multiple platforms. Are you running it on Windows? If so, it's limited to the Windows Python, of course…

Comment: I was about to say it uses custom python called pymel so may be the same across platforms, but I've just realised it's probably the normal python built in with maya modules imported, my mistake ;p

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem here is that you're using [`time.time`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.time).

On my MacBook Pro, `time.time` takes more than 1/3rd as long as all of the work you're doing:

```
In [2]: %timeit time.time()
10000000 loops, best of 3: 105 ns per loop

In [3]: %timeit  (((j+10)**0.5)**2)**0.5
1000000 loops, best of 3: 268 ns per loop
```

And that 105ns is *fast* for `time`—e.g., an older Windows box with no better hardware timer than ACPI can take 100x longer.

---

On top of that, `time.time` is not guaranteed to have enough precision to do what you want anyway:

> Note that even though the time is always returned as a floating point number, not all systems provide time with a better precision than 1 second.

Even on platforms where it has better precision than 1 second, it may have a lower accuracy; e.g., it may only be updated once per scheduler tick.

And `time` isn't even guaranteed to be monotonic; on some platforms, if the system time changes, `time` may go down.

---

Calling it less often will solve the first problem, but not the others.

So, what can you do?

Unfortunately, there's no built-in answer, at least not with Python 2.7. The best solution is different on different platforms—probably `GetTickCount64` on Windows, `clock_gettime` with the appropriate clock ID on most modern *nixes, `gettimeofday` on most other *nixes. These are relatively easy to use via `ctypes` if you don't want to distribute a C extension… but someone really should wrap it all up in a module and post it on PyPI, and unfortunately I couldn't find one…